# Laravel validation odd behavior

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs2

I'm working on a file upload and it upload well until I try to get a file I'm not supposed to be able to upload.

My rules are:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'media' => ['required', 'image', 'max:2000']
        ];
    }

public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'media.required' => 'You must give a file to upload!',
            'media.image'    => 'The file is not an image!',
            'media.max'      => 'The file is too big!',
        ];
    }
```

and when I try to upload a file which is 2,3Mo I got a 422 but the message is always The given data is invalid without telling me which one is invalid.

Then in my controller, this is how I use it:

```
public function uploadMedia(AddMediaRequest $request, MyEntity $entity)
    {
        $filename = $entity->addMedia($request->validated());

        return response()->json(['filename' => $filename], 200);
    }
```

Am I missing a simple point ? (I use Vue for the front end with axios)

Comment: Are you sure that it's Laravel and not your webserver/PHP configuration that stops you?

Comment: I run several website on this server and got no problem with others :/

Comment: But did you investigate? Did you check your server configuration? The default PHP configuration has a 2MB max for file uploads. This means that your file will never reach your Laravel application and it will be your PHP implementation (or your webserver) that rejects the request.

Comment: Yes I did, in php.ini, this is on 8MB and in nginx config, 128M   I receive a 422 and a laravel generic error message.

Comment: You are trying to upload 2,3Mb image, but max is  2000 Kb. The only strange thing here is that you don't get 'The file is too big' message.